# Is Mustache XSS-proof?

Tags: xss, mustache

I was thinking about my app's XSS vulnerability. On the server side I don't sanitize either input or output, so

```
<script>alert(document.cookies)</script>
```

is stored in database exactly so. To view this value on the client side I use Mustache. If this script was executed by an admin, it is of course easy to hijack his session. However I've noticed that Mustache by default escapes these values & \ " < > when you use the {{}} syntax. Do I need to worry about XSS, when the value from the database would be inserted into

```
<p>{{value}}</p>
```

or even

```
<p data-id='{{value}}'>something</p>
```

? Should I perhaps review my Mustache templates to look for any vulnerable code, or unless I'd use

```
<script>{{value}}</script>
```

I am safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should always worry :)  But yes, Mustache accomplishes the goal you are talking about here, protecting your examples from XSS (except where you're outputting the value directly into a `<script>` tag).

Note: check that the Mustache implementation you're using escapes single quotes. It's apparently not in the spec to do so (https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/69) but the major implementations thankfully escape it anyway.